# Mostrar el valor mínimo(que no sea 0) en una matriz en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, matriz

Soy nuevo en R y me gustaría sacar el elemento más pequeño sin contar los ceros de la matriz de distancias
He probado a hacer un bucle for e ir mirando elemento a elemento pero no controlo la sintaxis

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEzpw.png]

Comment: agrega tu codigo para que te expliquen el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tu matriz es una matriz simétrica. Sólo necesitas evaluar un lado de la matriz, ya sea el triángulo superior y el triángulo inferior.

Entonces para sacar el triángulo superior se usa la función `upper.tri()`

```
# Guardo la matriz en un objeto llamado matriz.
matriz<-mahalanobis.dist(iris[51:60,1:2])

# sacando el triángulo superior.
matriz[upper.tri(matriz)]

 [1] 1.3227992 0.3291962 1.4999377 2.6463130 2.9627662 2.3563372 1.2334631 2.0626547 0.9100079 1.5141122
[11] 1.8223872 1.1781686 1.7748160 2.0312107 1.7637322 1.9342480 0.6582861 2.1421064 3.5123957 2.7157911
[21] 1.5593231 2.8916256 2.3794963 2.7539991 1.7166709 2.3664214 1.2112897 2.6562719 0.9100079 1.7803321
[31] 0.5929061 1.7771427 0.3291962 1.6422325 2.4378823 2.4066555 2.5847160 1.6752090 2.5600763 2.4378823
[41] 2.5148101 0.7905448 1.7771427 0.9875887 2.4220012
```

aquí sólo aplicas la función `min()` para encontrar el valor mínimo.

```
min(matriz[upper.tri(matriz)])

0.3291962
```

Y listo. Lo puedes hacer también con el triángulo inferior usando la función `lower.tri()`. Te saldrá lo mismo porque tu matriz es simétrica.

Comment: Gracias! no se me había ocurrido